# Using the Google javascript client library in a native Mac app

Tags: javascript, google-api

I'm using the Google javascript client library for use with Google Drive to view and open files.

It works fine on my website but I would like this to work in a WebView in a native Mac app.

When I try to authorize my app in javascript in my WebView on Mac I get `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)`.

The problem is this URL parameter `origin=file://` in the request.

From what I've read this should be localhost but I don't know how to correct this through the client library.